# detect client on web application is local Or from internet

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

how can i know a client that in my web Application  connected  via Wan (from Internet ) OR use local network to connect .if there is function for it please tel me.

Comment: You could maybe use `Request.UserHostAddress` to get the client's IP?  But it *really* shouldn't matter.  What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: i want  ban user to see one of my pages  if user came from internet

Comment: Standard authentication/authorization techniques are *vastly* more effective than this.  Require authentication for that page.

Comment: i have a authentication/authorization but this page i'am talking about it is out side of may application authentication . i want to use qr code to save Attendance of my employees so user not yet authenticated so i just want user can not access it from internet

Comment: in .Net framework , we have `Request.IsLocal`  to check whether the request is from local server . https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.islocal%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup/host a small web service that's only available within your intranet and try to hit it from the client javascript.  If they are on your local network, it will be successful, else it will fail.

Comment: are you mean to setup a new iis website and bring project on it and ban internet from it so just any one that connected to local network can seen it

Comment: Yes, a new web service in IIS, but you don't necessarily have to ban internet.  The server just needs a non-public IP address (ie: local), so that internal devices can see it, but not public.  The web service might look like this: http://192.168.0.0/WebService/IsLocalService